# What are some nice software for customer event/activity analytics?

Tags: analytics, saas

For tracking events like Visited, Logged in, made a purchase, etc.

In short, it should be able to track every event or activity of a customer, and also includes a feature for analytics of the same.

PS: Mine is a SAAS startup, just in case this info would help while answering.